# Compare items from InlineFrom before saving Django

Tags: python, django

I have an InlineForm on my forms that I save a list of names, but I'd like to check if the names are different before saving it. When I try a FOR to save the names in a list, I get the individual letters instead. How can I solve this problem?

Here's my form and validation code:

forms.py

```
class ColabForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Colaboradores
    fields = '__all__'

colaborador_projeto = forms.CharField(label="Colaborador do Projeto", widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control col-8',
        'maxlength': '200',
    }
))

def clean(self):
    colaborador_projeto = self.cleaned_data.get('colaborador_projeto')

    lista_erros = {}

    verifica_nome(colaborador_projeto)

    if lista_erros is not None:
        for erro in lista_erros:
            mensagem_erro = lista_erros[erro]
            self.add_error(erro, mensagem_erro)
    return self.cleaned_data
```

validation.py

```
def verifica_nome(colaborador_projeto):

lista_nomes = {}
loop = 0
for nome in colaborador_projeto:
    lista_nomes[loop] = nome
    loop += 1

print(lista_nomes)
```

Here's how the print shows:

{0: 'V', 1: 'i', 2: 'c', 3: 't', 4: 'o', 5: 'r'}
{0: 'J', 1: 'é', 2: 's', 3: 's', 4: 'i', 5: 'c', 6: 'a'}
{0: 'L', 1: 'e', 2: 't', 3: 'i', 4: 'c', 5: 'i', 6: 'a'}

P.S.: I know I'm not sending the errors list yet. I wanna solve the 'comparing names' problem first, before I send the error to my HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For in python separate string in char... In order for them to get together you have to use:

```
for nome in colaborador_projeto.split():
```

With this he will pick the string itself.

Comment: It kinda worked. But I'll have to ask another question to solve this problem.
It joined the letters into one name, but when working with surname, it made a new string.
{0: 'Victor', 1: 'Bitencourt'}
{0: 'Jéssica', 1: 'Dieckel'}
{0: 'Leticia', 1: 'Bitencourt'}
No I don't know how to save those names individually in a new arraylist.
Mas valeu pela resposta!

Comment: Ah beleza.. Nome e sobrenome.

For this just put in this way

for nome in colaborador_projeto.split(" ", 0):

default split pick the whitespace as a value to separate with this, I decide to take no whitespace in consideration